# CSS not load new file, only the previous file is loaded

Tags: html, css, user-interface, jquery-ui, styles

I have project. I used HTML and external CSS. But when I create CSS file and save it, it works. But when i add more data in the CSS file, It only load the previous CSS. The new CSS file i added recently it's not working.

So i have to always create new separate CSS file on every page before I save it. I don't know how to make it works using only single CSS file for my project on my base UI.
and if i copy that style to the body of HTML(inline CSS) it's totally working. But when i added that file into style.CSS it's not working unless i create new file CSS.
Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Please add more description to your question: How do you set up your test environment? Are you running a local development server or just click the HTML file (if this is the case that's probably why the browser cache your previous CSS file)

Answer (score 0):

The static resources are probably getting cached in your browser. Try to do hard-refresh your page by pressing `Ctrl + F5` or `Ctrl + click refresh button`.

https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/